# What can I use in select if I don't need column name

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a table A where columns from 2003 to 2025

I seed select all columns before current year.
For example if current year is 2017:

```
Select 2003 ,   
      2004 ,   
      2005 ,   
      2017,     
      2018 = CASE WHEN EXISTS (select 1 from another table) then "value" else "" END
```

From table A

I don't want to see in result the name of the column.

**i.e result of select should be:

 2003 2004 2005.....2017

if current year is 2018 than

2003 2004 2005.....2017 2018**

Can I do it in SYBASE 15 in stored procedure?

Comment: I've read this several times, and I still can't quite tell what you are asking.  Can you give a better example of the output you are currently getting, and  the output you wish to get?  Are you trying to eliminate all the column headers, a single column header, or a single column (header & data)?

Comment: I want to eliminate a single column header if this column is greater than current year

Comment: Dynamic sql within stored procedure creating list of column fields and then executing the query.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that in order to have a variable "shape" to your result set you need to use dynamic SQL. Where by "shape" I mean the type and number of columns.

So you would declare a string and use logic to build an appropriate query which then is executed.

Comment: our company forbade to use dynamic SQL. is there any other way?